# PostgreSQL16 on Windows - Clean up pg_wal archive location

Tags: postgresql

Local pg_wal is cleaning up like it should. And pg_wal\archive_status has all the file with .done (Example: 0000000100000004000000DE.done). Archive_mode is set to on and archive_command is copying to a data domain. I'm also running pg_basebackup nightly at 11:00pm (still need to write batch to clean anything older than x days). Requirement is to be able to restore to anytime since last backup; which in my case will be last night.

The problem that I'm trying to resolve now is cleaning up the archive_command data domain.
It doesn't look like the files had been cleaned up since I set it up 1/11/2024 (per advise from [PostgreSQL 16 pg_wal folder vs pg_wal\archive_status](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334705/postgresql-16-pg-wal-folder-vs-pg-wal-archive-status)). Will PostgreSQL automatically cleanup the data domain archive files? The files I have are 16.0MB (example: 0000000100000000000000F9) with a (0000000100000000000000F9.00000380.backup) during pg_basebackup time at 11:00pm.

Will I have to write a .bat to delete those files?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps if you used a program designed for the purpose, such as Barman, you wouldn't need to roll your own scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't take care of your archived WAL segments. It doesn't even know they exist — all it does is execute the `archive_command`.

You can use `pg_archivecleanup` with the file from the oldest backup you may need to recover:

```bash
pg_archivecleanup /archived/wal/location 0000000100000000000000F9.00000380.backup
```

or you can simply have a regularly scheduled job that removes all archived WAL that is older than X days.

Comment: A little weird to me - knows to execute archive_command ; but, doesn't know they exists for clean up. Weird to me anyway.    Appreciate the confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: What's the archive_cleanup_command on postgresql.conf used for?

Comment: Never mind. - archive_cleanup_command is for hot_standby replica server?

Comment: @Student Right.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate your suggestions mustaccio. We just have the *one* dev server and *one* prod server to support *one* 3rd party software. Management doesn't see this growing for the next 5 years. Vendor of the 3rd party doesn't even provide any support. We are primarily Oracle environment.

Got pg_archivecleanup working manually based on https://documentation.tricentis.com/qtest/9910/en/content/qtest_onpremise/advanced_server_administration/continuous_wal_archiving_for_windows.htm

Will research on automating it via postgresql.conf